# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, localhost

I looked at many threads here, but no luck

I am new to `Spring` and working on the *Getting started guides* on the example [Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

When I execute the below command in the URL box: http://localhost:8080/health

I get this error,

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Feb 03 13:33:46 CET 2016
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>
> No message available

I have made no changes to the code and have also followed the same naming convection.

### my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please advice.
Regards,

Comment: Please post some configuration, e.g. of your controller. Also, when you run your application, is there something similar to RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/health]} in the console?

Comment: @Lukehy, here it is `package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}`

Comment: Does plain http://localhost:8080 work?

Comment: No... i mentioned that localhost:8080 works... but localhost:8080/health gives me the error, which i mentioned... I am using same code from link i posted (spring boot guide)

Comment: Then you probably haven't added the spring-boot-starter-actuator properly. Are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: I have now added to pom file also ... please have a look...

Comment: Hum, that seems fine, again the question, when you start your application, do any of the actuator EndpointHandlerMappings  (/health, /info, /metrics) show in your console?

Comment: @Lukehey, i dont see any of those in the console. in the output when i run - mvn package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667372/spring-boot-web-app-not-working-on-tomcat-404-error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the correct package structure in your project. Basically you should locate your main application class in a root package above other classes. At the same time avoid putting the main application in the default package.

[Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) suggests the following structure:

```
com
+- example
 +- myproject
     +- Application.java
     |
     +- domain
     |   +- Customer.java
     |   +- CustomerRepository.java
     |
     +- service
     |   +- CustomerService.java
     |
     +- web
         +- CustomerController.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Be Careful!!! use devtools! without devtools you will have Whitelabel Error Page and impossible enter to h2 console(If you are using jpa and h2 database for running on localhost) or maybe writing data using SQL in your src/main/resources folder. Try it, hopefully it helps. Even I got stuck at the same problem.

Add dependency in pom.xml and remember always restart the application no matter it's state after making changes in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>    
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>    
</dependency>
```