# Spring boot web app not working on Tomcat - 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Note: There are similar questions to this one but none of the solutions work for me. I've spent a few days trying to get this to work.

I've deployed a WAR file to Tomcat and the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" shows that it has started. When I click on the web app "/forecaster" I get a 404 error. The web app works when running from the debugger (IntelliJ). The WAR file is named "forecaster.war" and the paths I've tried are:
http://localhost:8080/forecaster/
http://localhost:8080/forecaster/forecast/
http://localhost:8080/forecaster/forecast/1

"Catalina.sh start" output:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomecat 
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomecat 
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomecat/temp 
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home 
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomecat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomecat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
Tomcat started.
```

Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.4.3.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'

jar {
    baseName = 'forecaster'
    version = '0.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootRun {
   addResources = true
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

ForecasterApplication.java:

```
package com.brian.project.forecaster;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.spring
```

framework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ForecasterApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ForecasterApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ForecasterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ForecastController.java:

```
package com.brian.project.forecaster.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.brian.project.forecaster.services.DatabaseRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ForecastController {

   @Autowired
   private DatabaseRepository databaseRepository;

   @RequestMapping(value = "forecast/{id}")
   public String getForecastForChain(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException
   {

      model.addAttribute("futureForecastData", "Say 404 again I dare you...");
      model.addAttribute("storeName", "test store name");

      return "forecast";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions here instead of using IntelliJ.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#_run_the_application

To run the application locally:

```
./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/forecaster/forecaster-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

To build the war I added to the build.gradle file:

```
war {
    baseName = 'forecaster'
    version = '0.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Then I ran:

```
./gradlew build
```

This produced the WAR file here:

> build/libs/forecaster/forecaster-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

And I copied that to the external Tomcat8 server (where /external-test/ is the mounted samba folder mounted to /Library/Tomcat/webapps):

```
cp build/libs/forecaster/forecaster-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.war /external-test/forecaster.war
```

Now it works with this URL:

> http://localhost:8080/forecaster/forecast/1

Comment: Damn Thanks a ton man you saved me , i have been at it for hours , I tried running it from the IDE running the main class as java application , using mvn install and and java -jar nothing worked , same 404 , only the instructions in the article worked for running , still not sure why

Comment: @Sam2016 You're welcome. It definitely took me a while to get it working.